# Using Swagger-PHP on non-oo project

Tags: swagger, swagger-php

currently for a project, I need to create documentation for it using Swagger. Since the project is done in php, I am going to use Swagger-Php to annotate the code and create the documentation. Now I have noticed that in all the example projects, they are all objected-oriented; in other words, when a request is made, a call to a controller is made, which in turn calls the model, etc. In the project I am a part of, the project is not organized this way: each page has its own file, and takes care of all the operations within that file. How would I use Swagger to document code in this way?

For example, the following pseudocode is essentially what each file does:

```
<?php
    //get paramters
    //query database
    //return json file, either data or status of the operation
?>
```

Would I do something like this?

```
<?php
    /*
     * @SWG\Resource(
     * apiVersion="1.0",
     * basePath="http://url.com/exampleFile"
     * )
     * */
    /* @SWG\Api(
     * @SWG\Operation(
     * summary="Retreives data from database and prints out in json",
     * method="GET",
     * type="", // what would go here?
     * @SWG\Parameter(name="param1",type="string"),
     * @SWG\Parameter(name="param2",type="int")
     * )
     * )
     * */
     //How will I show example of json to be printed to the user?

    //get paramters
    //query database
    //return json file, either data or status of the operation
?>
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figured this out months ago, but forgot to update this post. The object-oriented method will automatically be able to create the api for you with your annotations. If you are not using this method, then in each file, you will have to manually add everything, as shown above.